# Django urls does not work with reverse

Tags: django, django-urls

I have this config

settings.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project.urls'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^any_url/', Foo, name="something")
)
```

With this config my project works but if I use `reverse('something')` it breaks.

Besides, If I change my settings file to `ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project.my_project.urls'` reverse works but my project breaks.

Why? what am I doing wrong?

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named urls
```

If change my settings I get:

```
No module named my_project.urls
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Please paste it in full if possible.

Comment: when you run django: are you running the runserver in the project path?: `python manage.py runserver` (the same directory); if you run it from apache/wsgi: are you including the right PythonPath directive?; if running it from gunicorn: are you in the project directory, so you specify "wsgi:application" as module?

Comment: try: reverse("appname:something")

Comment: I get `ImportError: No module named urls`

Comment: Try changing it to just urls and see if that works.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli I run `python manage.py runserver` in the project path

Answer (score 0):

Use this in urls. py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```